# $ S = \{(x,y) \in B \times B | (\exists a,b \in A)[f(a)=x, f(b)=y, (a,b) \in R ] \} $ with R transitive, is S transitive?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

Be the funtion $ f: A \to B $ and $ R \subseteq A \times A $ a transitive relation. Be the relation $ S \subseteq B \times B $ defined as:

$ S = \{ (x,y) \in B \times B | (\exists a,b \in A)[f(a)=x, f(b)=y, (a,b) \in R ] \} $

Is S transitive? Which changes will be enough to S be transitive?

Answers:

I know S is not transitive, a counter-example is: $ A = \{ 1,2,3,4 \} $, $ B = \{ u,v,w \}$, $ f = \{ (1,u), (2,v), (3,v), (4,w) \} $ and $ R = \{ (1,2), (3,4) \}$

R is transitive. $ (u,v) \in S $, $ (v,w) \in S $, but $ (u,w) \notin S $

But don't have idea how make S transitive. If I change $ (x,y) \in B \times B $ to some relation transitive in B I tought that solved, but i'm not certain.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can replace $S$ with its [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure)? It's difficult to know what the question is trying to get at.

Comment: **Hint:** You are being asked what *kind* of function must $f$ be to  make $S$ transitive.

Comment: @dantopa thanks

Comment: @TheoBendit I don't think so, because my teacher don't tell us about the transitive closure yet, just the simple definition of transitive relation. I agree it's difficult, the question isn't clear, but the teacher wrote that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to make S transitive:-
1. S will be always transitive if the function f is one-one and R is transitive.
2. If f is not injective, define R in such a way that functional image of first element of the ordered pair in R is not equal to the functional image of any second element of the other ordered pair.
e.g. (from the example stated above)
         if R = {(1,2),(1,3)} => S={(u,v)} is transitive
  Or
          if R = {(2,3), (4,1)} then S = {{(v,v), (w,u)} is transitive.

Answer (score 0):

Assume f in an injection.
If aSb, bSc, then exists x,y,z,t in A with
f(x) = a, f(y) = b, f(z) = b, f(t) = c.
Since y = z and xRy, zRt comes xRt and aSc.